# Xorg does not show up in ps aux?

Tags: xorg, ps

Doing `ps aux` on tty1 does not list Xorg as a process, but commands like `killall Xorg` work fine. Why does ps not list Xorg?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process command line actually shows `X`, not `Xorg`:

```
$ ps aux | grep -w X
muru     14702  0.0  0.0  15940   956 pts/6    S+   12:33   0:00 grep -w X
root     30664  1.9  1.6 690024 136632 tty7    Ssl+ Jun16 215:33 /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
$ pgrep X -a
30664 /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
```

Interestingly, `pgrep Xorg` returns the same process:

```
$ pgrep Xorg -a
30664 /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
```

And even more interesting, *expanding* `pgrep`'s search criteria then fails to work:

```
$ pgrep Xorg -fa
$
```

This is because [`X` (`/usr/bin/X`) is a wrapper that calls `Xorg`](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2012/09/msg00002.html). I believe (but am not sure) it actually [`exec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/exec.3)s, and so the command line, which is what `ps` shows, remains unchanged and the program is now different. This can be verified by examining the process' `/proc` directory:

```
$ sudo ls -l /proc/30664/exe 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 24 08:09 /proc/30664/exe -> /usr/bin/Xorg
```

This is why `pgrep Xorg` and `killall Xorg` work, but `pgrep -f Xorg` failed. `pgrep -f` searches the command lines, which still show `X`, not `Xorg`. So an action which should usually return better results, actually has worse results.

---

Indeed, it seems `X` does `exec`. Using [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13280752/2072269):

```
$ nm -D /usr/bin/X  | grep exec
                 U execv
```

Comment: Good to know that X process and Xorg are the same (almost)